# Assign awk output to variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to assign the output of awk to variable. I tried with solutions specified here but nothing seems to work. I'm first doing curl and then parsing the result from there

```
#!/bin/sh 

KEY="title"

curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | statu=$(awk -F'[,:}]' 
'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$KEY'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}'  | tr -d '"')

echo "This is status" "$statu"
```

Comment: curl should be inside the $(...) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use command substitution like follows:

```
#!/bin/sh 

KEY="title"

statu=$(curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 | awk -F'[,:}]' 
'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$KEY'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}'  | tr -d '"')

echo "This is status" "$statu"
```

Comment: Awk can remove a double quote just fine; simply replace the `tr -d '"'` with something like `sub(/\042/, "", $(i+1))` inside the Awk script before printing.

Comment: Oh yeah, i used the substitution in wrong place. Thank you very much!